# ajax request acting strange

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having difficulty sending a variable together with an ajax request. Here is my html/js code:

```
    <input id="login-username" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Username"/>

<input id="login-password" class="input" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="submit-login" class="btn btn-small btn-info"><strong>sign in</strong></a>

$("#submit-login").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var usernameReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
    var username = $("#login-username").val();
    var password = $("#login-password").val();
    alert(username);
    alert(password);
    if(!usernameReg.test(username)){
        $("#input-login-username").html("some html");
        return false;
    } else if(!usernameReg.test(password)){
        $("#input-login-password").html("some html");
        return false;
    } else if((username == "") || (password = "")){
        $("#input-login-username").html("<strong><small>Empty field(s)</small></strong>");
        return false;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '?a=validate',
            data: {
                "password" : password,
                "username" : username
            },
            success: function(data){
                some statements
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[image]

[image]

The value of the password element is received as displayed in the first image. And there are no misspellings in the object literal that is send with the ajax. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=` ≠ `==`:

```
} else if((username == "") || (password = "")){
```

Comment: Thanks missed that. But dont think that will solve my problem.

Comment: @user1683645 It sets your password equal to `""`, which is what your post request shows.

Comment: There is a timer preventing me from doing it for x amount of minutes after submitting a post.